Reciprocal Discriminant function is a modular form
I came across a problem that any cusp form of order k, (say f) can be written as product of Discriminant function and a modular function of order k-12 say, h.
So i took $h=\frac{f}{\Delta}$ since $\Delta$
Is of order 12
Which implies h is of order K-12.
I know h is modular
I have order k-12
Now i have to show that is has fourier expansion $h(\tau)= {\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n} c(k)e^{2πik\tau} $ --(•)
So i know $\frac{f}{\Delta}$ is periodic , only thing i want to prove that $\frac{f}{\Delta}$ at $|(i \infty)|$ is finite

By standard complex analysis, if holomorphic functions $f, g$ have a zeros of orders $a, b$ respectively at a point $z_0$ with $a \geq b$, then $f/g$ may be extended to a holomorphic function near $z_0$. This continues to work in the chart at infinity in the context of modular forms.

Notice that $\Delta$ has a simple zero at $i\infty$ and nozero elsewhere in the fundamental domain.

Okay, now i understand
